# How to wire or autowire think properly?

Tags: spring, hibernate

I like spring, I like those annotations, save me a lot of time. But it also give me headed. So can someone explain for me about @Autowired plz?

I followed some tutorial and here is what I got:

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class    org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'registerController': 
Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.isad.dao.UserAccountDAO 
com.isad.controller.RegisterController.userAccount; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.isad.dao.UserAccountDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

My Pojo:

```
private int id;
private String username;
private String email;
private String password;
```

My Dao:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class UserAccountDAOImpl implements UserAccountDAO{
@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
public UserAccount getById(int id) {
    return (UserAccount) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                                    .get(UserAccount.class, id);
}
public int save(UserAccount aUser) {
    return (Integer)sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(aUser);
}
}
```

My Controller:

```
@Autowired
private UserAccountDAO userAccount;
@Autowired
private UserAccountFormValidator validator;

@RequestMapping(value="register", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String registerPage(@ModelAttribute("newUserAccount") UserAccount aUser,
                        BindingResult result) {
    System.out.println("inside register post");
    validator.validate(aUser, result);
    if( result.hasErrors()) {
        return "register";
    }
    userAccount.save( aUser );
    return "../../index";
}
```

UserAccountFormValidator:

```
@Component("useraccountFormValidator")
public class UserAccountFormValidator implements Validator{
@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> arg0) {
    return UserAccount.class.isAssignableFrom( arg0 );
}
@Override
public void validate(Object arg0, Errors arg1) {
    ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(arg1, "name", "required");
}
}
```

Comment: Where is your context file ?

Answer (score 0):

The package `com.isad.dao` of `UserAccountDAOImpl` is likely not being scanned for Spring beans. Check your Spring configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your spring config file provide this:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.isad"/>
```